# Caching an object on the server for cross page access

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, youtube-data-api

I'm looking for an easy way to create a server side cached instance of an `object` so that I can refer to it upon later return. Basically, I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core in C# on a .NET web application. In a controller I call `TutorialsController` I have an action result for index that gets a collection of my videos and displays them on the index view. Then, when I select one of the videos, I want to go back to the previous controller and use a cached version of the original collection to retrieve the selected video `object`. I'm thinking that using some sort of server side caching would do the trick so I don't have to keep calling the YouTube API a bunch of times.

If you have any answers for server side caching or any other technique, I'd appreciate the feedback.

Thanks

Comment: are you using a single server or several servers with a load balancer?

Comment: Thank you for your response @user2033402. That's a good question. I am currently developing and testing the application in Visual Studio 2017, which uses a type of IIS Express. However, I plan on hosting it in an Azure Web App; most likely without the use of any additional load balancing as far as my best guess. As far as I know, the subscription plan I use for this project does not include load balancing across multiple instances. I hope this answers your question. Look foreward to your response.

Comment: There's a caching api in ASP.NET, you can check it out first here if you think this will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx
Otherwise you will need to check out Redis

Comment: If you using one server, i advise to using memory cache.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Because the OP mentions **MVC Core App** without the use of a Load Balancer please take a look at **In-Memory** caching provided by the `IMemoryCache` interface.

The following link to Microsoft documentation explains well how to set this up:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed

Within the documentation, there is mention the use of **distributed caching** using the `IDistributedCache` interface, only if you need it when/if you decide to host multiple instances.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed